# ruby optionnal argument unexpected *

Tags: ruby

I have this very simple piece of code (using Ruby 3)

```
def eat(main, dessert*)
  if dessert.empty?
    puts "I eat #{main}"
  else
    puts "I eat #{main} than #{dessert}."
  end
end
```

Wher I run `eat("mushrooms")` that provokes errors:

```
argu.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected '*', expecting ')'
def manger(plat, dessert*)
argu.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected `end', expecting end-of-input
```

I don't see why.

Comment: See the docs for [Array/Hash Argument](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Array-2FHash+Argument): _"**Prefixing** an argument with * causes any remaining arguments to be converted to an Array"_ (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you got the idea from using `dessert*`, but you could define your method as

```
def eat(main, dessert = [])
```

to provide a default argument (of course it must be one which can respond to `empty?`).

Of course it is up to you to justify, why "main" can be anything (i.e. a `String`), but `dessert` must be a collection. I would test for dessert as

```
if dessert.nil?
```

and hence provide `nil` as default value for the dessert.

Comment: excellent ! `dessert = []` allows to use `puts "I eat #{dessert}"` and `dessert = nil` obliges `puts "I eat #{dessert[0]}"`.

Comment: But you have to be happy with the way `Array#to_s` formats it argument, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Splat operator should put before parameters so your signature should be

> def eat(main, *dessert)